# Sum an array of arrays by position resulting in one array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of arrays of `Int` and I want to sum every value within all the values in the same position in a performing way. For example:

```
let array: [[Int]] = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

The result should be:

```
let result: [Int] = [11, 14, 11, 9]
```

If this is too complex, I can make all subarrays to have the same amount of elements.

My current soultion is the following but I believe it has to be a cleaner and more efficient way of doing it:

```
func sumElementsInSubArrays(_ array: [[Int]]) -> [Int] {
        var result: [Int] = []
        for subarray in array {
            for (i, value) in subarray.enumerated() {
                if result.count > (i) {
                    result[i] = result[i] + value
                } else {
                    result[i] = value
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @FabioFelici I have it in a dirty not very nice performance way (nested loops)  and I feel it has to be possible with `reduce` but I haven't manage to make it work.

Comment: Does your current solution give an Index out of bounds error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be several ways like HOF to deal with this situation but if you are new to it like me , you can do it like this :

Considering all the subArrays to have same number of element :

```
let array = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 2, 7, 0] , [1, 7, 9, 4]]

        var finalArray = [Int]()
        for i in 0..<(array.first?.count ?? 0) {
            var aElement = 0
            array.forEach { aArray in
                aElement += aArray[i]
            }
            finalArray.append(aElement)
        }
```

//Final array should look like this at this point : [7, 11, 19, 8]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a couple of nested loops (I don't think performance wise using reduce would be faster, thought it may look better/debatably be better for readability):

```
func sumElementsInSubArrays(_ array: [[Int]]) -> [Int] {
    var result: [Int] = []
    for subarray in array {
        for (i, value) in subarray.enumerated() {
            if result.count > i {
                result[i] += value
            } else {
                result.append(value)
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}

print(sumElementsInSubArrays([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]))
print(sumElementsInSubArrays([]))
print(sumElementsInSubArrays([[]]))
```

**Output:**

```
[11, 14, 11, 9]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Do you really need to find `maxLength`?

Comment: No, but using append is amortized O(1). Sometimes creating the desired length before the loop is faster.